# Angular 5: missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I followed this article for customizing UI components:

```
https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/docs/articles/auth-ui.md
```

But after that lots of errors started occuring due to files not found. Article says to just copy component folder. I fixed all of them but now getting error that:

```
Module build failed: Error: C:\xampp\htdocs\utahclient\src\app\@theme\components\auth\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

http://prntscr.com/ji9gp0

Below is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
],
"plugins": [
  { "name": "tslint-language-service"}
]
}
}
```